# Is there a way to write a glob pattern that matches to either a file within a directory or a whole directory within that same directory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, glob

I'm trying to write a glob pattern that will match to either the cloudbuild.yaml file or anything in the API directory in this structure:

```
Server/
├── API/
│   ├── script.js
│   ├── somethingelse.html
├── Excluded Directory/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── cloudbuild.yaml
```

I've tried this so far and while I can get individual parts of it to match I can't seem to get it to match either pattern with the same pattern:

```
Server/{API/**, cloudbuild.yaml}
```

In case it's relevant, this is so my Cloud Build trigger will only trigger a redeploy if files within the API folder are updated, or if the cloudbuild.yaml file itself is.

Comment: does it have to be a glob or is a regular expression allowable?

Comment: it has to be a glob, that's what's allowed in the Cloud Build trigger filter unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is wondering, it's actually pretty easy - I was just missing a few slashes and this works:

```
/Server/{cloudbuild.yaml,API/*}
```